# How to design 4 diamond shapes(rhombus) and 8 triangles in a square(Kundli Design) using Html and Css

Tags: html, css

I want to insert 4 Diamond Shapes(Rhombus) and 8 Triangles in a Square. By searching in stack overflow, I have already designed 90% of it. But now, I stuck with a problem which is as shown in [PLUNKER DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eMw3nCzChYlQxuZDXI2d?p=preview). ***I want to join the 2 Shapes shown in Plunker***. Can anyone help me, by **editing the same PLUNKER DEMO,** since I need the control of all 12 individual shapes(so that I can insert a label in those shapes)..Thanks in Advance..

```css
.square1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -18px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
}

.square2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -256px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

.square3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -18px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  margin-top: -265px;
}

.square4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -256px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

polygon {
  fill: aliceblue;
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='square1'>
          <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
          <polygon id="t1" points='5,5 50,50 95,5' />
        
        <polygon id="t2" points='5,5 50,50 5,95' />
        <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95 50,145' />
        <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95 145,50' />
      </svg>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='square2'>
          <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
          <polygon id="t1" points='5,5 50,50 95,5' />
        
        <polygon id="t2" points='' />
        <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95 50,145' />
        <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95' />
      </svg>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class='square3'>
          <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
          <polygon id="t1" points='' />
        
        <polygon id="t2" points='5,5 50,50 5,95' />
        <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95' />
        <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95 145,50' />
      </svg>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class='square4'>
          <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
          <polygon id="t1" points='' />
        
        <polygon id="t2" points='' />
        <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95' />
        <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95' />
      </svg>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here is the fixed code:

```css
.square1 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -18px;
  border-right:none;
  border-left:none;
}
.square2 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -256px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
}
.square3 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -18px;
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
     margin-top: -128px;
}
.square4 {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -256px;  
  border-left:none;
  border-right:none;
  margin-top:-135px;
  position: relative;
    top: 12px;
  
}

svg {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
polygon {
  fill: aliceblue;
  stroke: crimson;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}
polygon:hover {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><td>
<div class='square1'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <polygon id="t1" points='5,5 50,50 95,5' />
    <text x="33" y="26" font-size="20" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width=".06">a10</text>
    <polygon id="t2" points='5,5 50,50 5,95' />
    <text x="10" y="56" font-size="20" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width=".06">a20</text>
    <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95 50,145' />
    <text x="36" y="96" font-size="20" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width=".06">a30</text>
    <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95 145,50' />
    <text x="80" y="56" font-size="20" fill="black" stroke="black" stroke-width=".06">a40</text>
  </svg>
</div></td><td>
<div class='square2'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <polygon id="t1" points='5,5 50,50 95,5' />
    
    <polygon id="t2" points='' />
    <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95 50,145' />
    <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95' />
  </svg>
</div></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
<div class='square3'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <polygon id="t1" points='' />
    
    <polygon id="t2" points='5,5 50,50 5,95' />
    <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95' />
    <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95 145,55' />
  </svg>
</div></td><td>
<div class='square4'>
  <svg viewBox='0 0 150 150'>
      <polygon id="t1" points='' />
    
    <polygon id="t2" points='' />
    <polygon id="t3" points='5,95 50,50 95,95' />
    <polygon id="t4" points='95,5 50,50 95,95' />
  </svg>
</div></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks...helped me lot

Comment: can I include label, for each shapes..If yes, can you post it @Sahil

Comment: using <text></text > and adjusting its x="" , y="" you can add labels.. updated my answer.. kindly check

Comment: yes...got, thanq..But I need to include **label** inside the <div></div> tag..Any Idea?..

Comment: you can achieve this but it will use the concept of position absolute on every element as you are using svg + polygon

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a samle code , hope you do this**

```css
.diamond {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  border: 50px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top-width: 0;
  border-bottom: 70px solid #1abc9c;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
}

.diamond::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 70px;
  left: -50px;
  border: 50px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
  border-top: 70px solid #1abc9c;
  font: normal 100%/normal Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: rgba(0,0,0,1);
  -o-text-overflow: clip;
  text-overflow: clip;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="diamond"></div>
```